# Reading response cookie from another domain server in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, axios, samesite

We are testing the situation of sending and receiving cookies with the server.

**When the client makes a request to the server, it reads the cookie in the response and tries to use it for the next request, and the client and server have different domains.**

SameSite policy has changed since Chrome 80 version, so I set it as follows.

Javascript (client), Axios

```
    axios.post("https://[SERVER_URL]", {}, {
      withCredentials: true,
    }),
```

Node.js (server)

```
    res.cookie("test", "cookieTest", {
    httpOnly: false,
    sameSite: "none",
    secure: true,
  });
```

Both client/server are running in HTTPS environment.

I tested it in this situation, but in the Response Cookies in the Network tab of Chrome's developer tools, the cookie given by the server is checked.
However, it is not stored in the cookie storage, and even if you try to read the value with document.cookie, it cannot be read.

I would like to ask if there is anything I missed or if I am testing because of the wrong approach.

Comment: A cookie set for a different domain, can of course not be read using `document.cookie`. Apart from that, your description is a bit unclear - unclear what exactly you want to achieve, unclear where exactly the problem is supposed to lie.